# Driving SUVs in the Namibian desert

Tags: car-rentals, africa

In one of the episodes of Grand Tour, Jeremy, Richard and James drive beach buggies on the beach of Namibia. At the end of the show, they thanked the government of Namibia for allowing them to shoot their program in this area. Is it possible for us as well to rent an SUV there and drive it alongside the coast of Namibia? Do we need a special permit of any sort or military protection? This is a picture of the coast from a drone:[image]

Comment: The thanks to the government might just be because it was filmed on public or state land. The same as thanking Disneyland if they filmed there.

Answer (score 4):

There are no restrictions, according to the official [Namibia Tourism](http://www.namibiatourism.com.na/page/transportation), and exploring by car is encouraged as the best way to see the country. It offers detailed [route maps available](http://www.namibiatourism.com.na/tourismroute) in multiple formats (online, pdf, high res e-mag). You do not need a permit to drive on the sections of beaches where it is allowed and posted; in some areas there are dedicated paths you must use. To rent a vehicle, you would need your national driving license, along with an International Driving Permit (IDP) (translated to English if your home country license is not).

Answer (score 3):

Yes You can (or could), because I did it in 2011 and visited many of the same places as the Grand Tour trio did - go do it, its fun.  Just dont break down or get lost - Namibia is a lovely but huge and desolate place.